# Layover in US with L2 visa

Tags: usa, transit, layovers

I am travelling from Toronto to Netherlands and have layover in US for 2 hours.
I have L2 visa and my husband is in US. He is travelling to Netherlands the next day.

Could you please confirm if L2 visa is valid for layover.

Comment: Is your husband still in valid L-1 status?

Comment: Yes he has valid visa for more than 2 years

Comment: Okay, but is he still working for the same employer?  If he has left that job then he is probably no longer in valid status and you would probably need a transit visa (or ESTA if you are eligible), unless you are a citizen of Canada or Bermuda.

Comment: He is still working for the same employer and will return the same day I return from Netherlands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use your L-2 visa to enter the US (including for transit), you have to be eligible for L-2 status.  L-2 status applies to dependents of someone in L-1 status, which, in your case, is your husband.

You've indicated that your husband, from whose L-1 status your L-2 status is derived, continues to work for his employer in the US.  So there is no reason to think that his L-1 status has lapsed, which means that you are eligible to enter in L-2 status, which means that you can use your L-2 visa for your planned transit.